# Where is this margin/padding coming from

Tags: jquery, slide, slidetoggle

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/46/

When clicking on 'MISC' or 'MISC2', their respective menus slide open. However it's not smooth; at the very top, there's some odd margin or padding that gets animated, making the menu slide animation stop for a moment while something unidentified gets animated, and then snap open/closed.

Can't seem to locate the cause. Many thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('.menu ul').slideUp(0);

    jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function () {
        var target = jQuery(this).children('a');
        if(target.hasClass('menu-expanded')){
            target.removeClass('menu-expanded');
        }else{
            jQuery('.menu-item > a').removeClass('menu-expanded');
            target.addClass('menu-expanded');
        }
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
                    .slideToggle(2000)
                    .end()
                    .siblings('li')
                    .find('ul')
                    .slideUp(2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've noticed that it has gray background color, just like its parent, so It might be related to css inherit , try css-resetting for the child's elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracked the issue down to `ul.sub-menu`'s `display:inline-block;`
Should be `display:block;` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/53/

Answer (score 0):

remove the position fixed from #menu...or change to position:relative;

```
#menu{
 position:relative;
}
```